# Else statement in Angular

Tags: angular, if-statement, conditional-statements

How does angular2 propose to render

```
<div *ngFor="let todo of unfinishedTodos">
    {{todo.title}}
</div>
```

in case if `unfinishedTodos.length >0`

and text "empty" in another cases.

**P.S.**

```
<div *ngIf="unfinishedTodos && unfinishedTodos.length > 0">
    <div *ngFor="let todo of unfinishedTodos">
        {{todo.title}}
    </div>
</div>
<div *ngIf="!unfinishedTodos ||  unfinishedTodos.length <= 0">
    empty
</div>
```

looks ugly

Answer (score 34, accepted):

**Syntax compatible with Angular 4.0 and beyond**

```
<ng-template #elseTemplate>
  Content displayed if expression returns false
</ng-template>
<ng-container *ngIf="expression; else elseTemplate">
  Content displayed if expression returns true
</ng-container>
```

or

```
<ng-container *ngIf="expression; then thenBlock; else elseBlock"></ng-container>
<ng-template #thenBlock>
  Content displayed if expression returns true
</ng-template>
<ng-template #elseBlock>
  Content displayed if expression returns false
</ng-template>
```

**Syntax compatible with Angular 2.0 and beyond**

```
<ng-container *ngIf="expression">
    true
</ng-container>
<ng-container *ngIf="!expression">
    else
</ng-container>
```

**Important**

- You can use e.g. `<div>`, or any other tag, instead of `<ng-container>`
- `<template>` had been deprecated since 4.0 in favor of `<ng-template>` to avoid name collision [with already existing tag.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template)

Answer (score 7):

With new Angular 4.0.0 syntax for else statement looks like this:

```
<div *ngIf="unfinishedTodos && unfinishedTodos.length > 0; else empty">
   <div *ngFor="let todo of unfinishedTodos">
      {{todo.title}}
   </div>
</div>
<ng-template #empty>
   empty
</ng-template >
```

Comment: Was too slow. Some more examples https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/aaf6e05f56c8a5493875f45af895132ea30729ad/modules/%40angular/examples/common/ngIf/ts/module.ts

Comment: I hope syntax it's going to be even nicer by the time release come.

Comment: In Angular 4.0 `<template>` is deprecated in favour of `<ng-template>`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<div *ngFor="let todo of unfinishedTodos">
    {{todo.title}}
</div>
<div *ngIf="!unfinishedTodos?.length">
    empty
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

CSS solution

```
<style>
    .empty { display: none; }
    .empty:only-child { display: block; }
</style>

<div>
    <div *ngFor="let todo of unfinishedTodos">
        {{todo.title}}
    </div>
    <div class="empty">
        empty
    </div>
</div>
```