# Conditionally eliminate list items in *ngFor - Angular 6

Tags: angular, html, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ngfor

I am trying to create a 4-column table using row-col div combination for a list with label and value items. The catch is - I don't wanna display any list item that does not have value in it. Not sure how to implement using *ngFor and *ngIf (as they both can't be used on the same element. Any help would be much appreciated. Here's my code sample

EDIT: Got it correct using `<ng-container>`. UPDATED code below

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="row" *ngIf="myList && myList.length > 0">

        <ng-container *ngFor="let myField of myList">

            <div class="col-6" *ngIf="myField.udfDisplayValue">

                <div style="width: 50%; display: inline-block">
                    <b>{{ myField.fieldName }}</b>
                </div>

                <div style="width: 50%; display: inline-block;">
                    {{ myField.displayValue }}
                </div>

            </div>
        </ng-container>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not sure if I understood exactly what you want, but you can use `*ngFor` on a `<ng-container>` element. Useful links https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives and https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-ng-template-ng-container-ngtemplateoutlet/

Comment: answered here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54429102/how-to-write-a-condition-with-ngfor-to-check-two-values/54429305#54429305

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Else statement in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41265553/else-statement-in-angular), or numerous other methods like simple css of like `div.col-6:empty { display:none }` or other techniques, just have to pick what's best for the instance.

Comment: @ChrisW. This helps. But using `<ng-container>` with ngFor provides a quick solution. Thanks!

Comment: @JoãoGhignatti. Using `<ng-container>` solved my problem. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

you can use [hidden] instead of *ngIf

Comment: I used `<ng-container *ngFor="condition">`. See my updated code above